# XOR classification using multilayer perceptrons is outputting 1 for all inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, xor

I'm using a neural network with 1 hidden layer (2 neurons) and 1 output neuron for solving the XOR problem.

Here's the code I'm using. It contains the main run file xor.py which creates a model defined in model.py. Each neuron is defined by the class Neuron in neuron.py

xor.py

```
from model import Model
import numpy as np

inputs = [[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]]
outputs = [0, 1, 1, 0]

m = Model()

m.train(inputs, outputs)

for i in inputs:
    p = m.predict(i)
    print str(i) + ' => ' + str(p)
```

model.py

```
from neuron import HiddenNeuron, OutputNeuron
import numpy as np

    class Model(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.hidden = [HiddenNeuron(2) for i in range(2)]
        self.output = OutputNeuron(2)

    def predict(self, input):
        temp = []
        for x in range(2):
            self.hidden[x].forward(input)
            temp.append(self.hidden[x].out)
        self.output.forward(temp)
        return self.output.out

    def train(self, inputs, targets):
        it = 0
        i = 0
        size = len(inputs)
        while it < 4:
            if i == size:
                i = 0
            feature = inputs[i]
            print '\n\nFeature : ' + str(feature) + '\n'
            print 'Output weights : ' + str(self.output.weights)
            print 'Hidden 1 weights : ' + str(self.hidden[0].weights)
            print 'Hidden 2 weights : ' + str(self.hidden[1].weights)
            temp = []
            for x in range(2):
                self.hidden[x].forward(feature)
                temp.append(self.hidden[x].out)
            self.output.forward(temp)
            self.output.backward(targets[i])
            deltas = []
            deltas.append(self.output.error)
            weights = []
            weights.append([self.output.weights[0]])
            weights.append([self.output.weights[1]])
            for x in range(2):
                self.hidden[x].backward(deltas, weights[x])
            for x in range(2):
                self.hidden[x].update(feature)
            self.output.update(temp)
            it += 1
            i += 1
```

neuron.py

```
import numpy as np
from random import uniform

class Neuron(object):

    def activation(self, fx):
        return 1/(1 + np.exp(-fx))

    def __init__(self, dim, lrate):
        self.dim = dim
        self.weights = np.empty([dim])
        self.weights = [uniform(0,1) for x in range(dim)]
        self.bias = uniform(0, 1)
        self.lrate = lrate
        self.out = None
        self.error = None

    def update(self, input):
        j = 0
        for i in input:
            delta = self.lrate * self.error
            self.weights[j] -= (delta*i)
            self.bias += delta
            j+=1

    def forward(self, input):
        j = 0
        sum = self.bias
        for f in input:
            sum += f * self.weights[j]
            j+=1
        self.out = self.activation(sum)

    def backward(self):
        pass

class OutputNeuron(Neuron):

    def __init__(self, dim, lrate=0.2):
        super(OutputNeuron, self).__init__(dim, lrate)

    def backward(self, target):
        self.error = self.out * (1 - self.out) * (self.out - target)


class HiddenNeuron(Neuron):

    def __init__(self, dim, lrate=0.2):
        super(HiddenNeuron, self).__init__(dim, lrate)

    def backward(self, deltas, weights):
        sum = 0
        size = len(deltas)
        for x in range(size):
            sum += deltas[x] * weights[x]
        self.error = self.out * (1 - self.out) * sum
```

The final output is

```
[0, 0] => 0.999999991272
[0, 1] => 0.999999970788
[1, 0] => 0.999999952345
[1, 1] => 0.999715564446
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is in neuron.py in the function update(). If you change `self.bias += delta` to `self.bias -= delta` it should work, at least it does for me. Otherwise you would modify your biases to ascend towards a maximum on the error surface.

Below you can see the output after 100000 training epochs.

`[0, 0] => 0.0174550173543
[0, 1] => 0.983899954593
[1, 0] => 0.983895388655
[1, 1] => 0.0164172288168`

Comment: Can you tell me why it works when I use minus instead of plus? Is there something I'm doing wrong? Because sometimes it doesn't work.

Comment: In order to find a (local or global) minimum of the loss function, you need to descent on the error surface as far as possible. The negative gradient always points in the direction of steepest descent, so you need the minus in order to update your weights and biases in the direction of the negative gradient. In your example, the weights were updated to minimize the loss function, but the biases were updated to maximize the loss function, which leads to some undesirable network behavior.